# Check if record inserted successfully

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, c#-4.0

The code here inserts data into a SQL Server table and it works fine but I could not know if that process was successfully or not. The code here shows error and it does not work as expected. How to use try and catch to check if data inserted or not.

Code

```
protected void btSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connection"].ToString());

    try
    {
        string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
        string contentType = FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType;

        using (Stream fs = FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream)
        {
            using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs))
            {
                byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((Int32)fs.Length);
                string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connection"].ConnectionString;

                con.Open();
                string query = "insert into events (comName,eventName, eventDis, eventDate,  fName, contentType, Data) values (@comName,@eventName,@eventDis, @eventDate,@fName, @contentType, @Data)";

                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
                {
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@comName", txtcname.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@eventName", txtename.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@eventDis", txteDis.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@eventDate", txteDate.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fName", filename);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContentType", contentType);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Data", bytes);

                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    con.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        return"Data not inserted !" + ex;
    }
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: return keyword must not be followed by an object expression

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to return a string from a void method or something like that.  Can't really tell since your code is incomplete.

Comment: Did you debug to see which line cause the error?

Comment: why you have `br, bytes, constr`? doesnt seem you are using it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like stated in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) :

For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the number of rows affected by the command. When a trigger exists on a table being inserted or updated, the return value includes the number of rows affected by both the insert or update operation and the number of rows affected by the trigger or triggers. For all other types of statements, the return value is -1. If a rollback occurs, the return value is also -1.

```
int a = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
if (a > 0) {
 //at least one record has been affected
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, your method is defined as `void`, so clearly, you can't return a string:

```
return"Data not inserted !" + ex;
```

I'm not clear on what you are trying to do here.  I would suggest removing the `try-catch` completely.  If something goes wrong, just let the exception propagate.  If everything runs normally, then it means that the insert worked ok.

<del>If you are really paranoid, I guess you could do as the other answer is suggesting and check that `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` returns `1`.  But for an `insert` statement, I find that kind of pointless.</del> I take that back. Checking for number of rows affected really is pointless in this case.  If the `insert` fails for some reason, it won't return `-1`, it will throw an exception.

BTW, consider wrapping the use of the `SqlConnection con` object with a `using` statement, the same way you are doing it for `SqlCommand cmd`.

**EDIT**

Assuming this is some WinForms application, and you just want to give the user some visual feedback if the insert worked or not, then you could try doing something like this:

```
try
{
    // do your sql stuff here.
    MessageBox.Show("Insert worked!");
}
catch(SqlException e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Data not inserted !" + e);
}
```

Comment: i am just trying to show message if data inserted successfully or not

Comment: try to log it in console instead or change return type to string

Answer (score 0):

Algiri, just like Juan said, you may want to show us what your error says.  Sql may not be allowing you to insert the record for a couple of reasons.

- For example, @comName may be set at 50 characters while the sql table has a max limit of 20 characters.

You said :

> "The code here inserts data into sql table and it works fine" 
>   When does it work fine? When running the command in SQL?